# Как улучшить код

Tags: python, ооп, классы, инспекция-кода

У меня есть задача
Реализовать сущность "точка", которая знает свои координаты, умеет определить расстояние до другой точки. Реализовать сущность "треугольник", при конструировании которого передаются три объекта-точки. Треугольник умеет отвечать на вопрос он существует, может вычислять свой периметр и площадь.
Вот мой код:

```
import math


class Point:

    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y

    def distance(self, B):
        return math.sqrt((self.X - B.X) ** 2 + (B.Y - self.Y) ** 2)


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3):
            self.p1 = p1
            self.p2 = p2
            self.p3 = p3
            if not self.is_existence():
                raise Exception("triangle does not exist")



    # @property
    # check if Triangle exists
    # if one point does not lie on another
    # if the length of one of the sides does not exceed the bag of the rest
    def is_existence(self):
        if (self.p1.X == self.p2.X and self.p1.Y == self.p2.Y) or \
                (self.p1.X == self.p3.X and self.p1.Y == self.p3.Y) or \
                (self.p2.X == self.p3.X and self.p2.Y == self.p3.Y):
            return False
        if self.p3.X * (self.p2.Y - self.p1.Y) - self.p3.Y * (self.p2.X - self.p1.X) \
                == self.p1.X * self.p2.Y - self.p2.X * self.p1.Y:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def perimeter(self):

            return (self.p1.distance(self.p2) + self.p1.distance(self.p3)
                    + self.p2.distance(self.p3)) / 2

    def area(self):
            s = math.sqrt(self.perimeter() * (self.perimeter() - (self.p1.distance(self.p2))) *
                          (self.perimeter() - (self.p1.distance(self.p3))) *
                          (self.perimeter() - (self.p2.distance(self.p3))))
            return s


myPoint1 = Point(1, 0)
myPoint2 = Point(300, 3)
myPoint3 = Point(0, 3)
myTriangle = Triangle(myPoint1, myPoint2, myPoint3)
print(myTriangle.perimeter())
print(myTriangle.area())
```

код поправил спасибо коментаторам но думаю можно его 
еще улучшить. (можно ли сюда добавить дескриптор?)

Comment: В Point.distance() нужно передавать одну точку, а не две, т.к. собственные координаты известны.

Comment: В `def area(self)` стоит сначала проверить треугольник на существование, а уже потом считать. Да и вообще что вам мешает кидать исключение в конструкторе, если треугольник, заданный переданными точками, не существует? Это позволит убрать все проверки из методов вычисления периметра и площади.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Улучшения:

1. оформить площадь, периметр и "существование" как свойства `@property`
2. Перегрузить оператор сравнения `__eq__` для точек
3. добавить вывод на печать (`__str__`) - мелочи оформления

import math

class Point:
    def **init**(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y

```
    def distance(self, B):
        return math.sqrt((self.X - B.X) ** 2 + (B.Y - self.Y) ** 2)

    def __eq__(self, B):
        return self.X == B.X and self.Y == B.Y

    def __str__(self):
        return '({X}, {Y})'.format(X=self.X, Y=self.Y)


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3):
            self.p1 = p1
            self.p2 = p2
            self.p3 = p3
            if not self.is_existence:
                raise Exception("triangle does not exist")

    @property
    def is_existence(self):
        """
        check if Triangle exists
        if one point does not lie on another
        if the length of one of the sides does not exceed the bag of the rest
        """
        if self.p1 == self.p2 or self.p1 == self.p3 or self.p2 == self.p3:
            return False

        if (self.p3.X * (self.p2.Y - self.p1.Y) -
            self.p3.Y * (self.p2.X - self.p1.X) 
                == self.p1.X * self.p2.Y - self.p2.X * self.p1.Y):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return (self.p1.distance(self.p2) + self.p1.distance(self.p3)
                    + self.p2.distance(self.p3)) / 2

    @property
    def area(self):
        return math.sqrt(
            self.perimeter * (self.perimeter - (self.p1.distance(self.p2))) *
              (self.perimeter - (self.p1.distance(self.p3))) *
              (self.perimeter - (self.p2.distance(self.p3))))


    def __str__(self):
        return '({p1}, {p2}, {p3})'.format(p1=self.p1, p2=self.p2, p3=self.p3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myPoint1 = Point(1, 0)
    myPoint2 = Point(300, 3)
    myPoint3 = Point(0, 3)

    print(myPoint1, myPoint2, myPoint3)
    print(myPoint3 == myPoint2)
    myTriangle = Triangle(myPoint1, myPoint2, myPoint3)
    print(myTriangle)
    print(myTriangle.perimeter)
    print(myTriangle.area)
```